# Error "Class Blog\Http\Requests does not exist" en el request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Al intentar hacer el registro de usuario me genera el error "Class Blog\Http\Requests does not exist"

Aquí mi **UsuarioController**

```
<?php

namespace Blog\Http\Controllers;



use Blog\Http\Requests;
use Blog\Http\Requests\CrearUsuarioRequests;
use Blog\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Blog\User;

class UsuarioController extends Controller{

    public function index(Request $request){
        $usuarios = User::name($request->get('name'))->orderBy('id','ASC')->paginate(15);
        return view('admin.usuario.index',compact('usuarios'));
    }

    public function create(){
        return view('admin.usuario.crear');        
    }

    public function store(Requests $request){
        dd($request->all());  
    }
}
```

y mi vista que esta en admin/usuario/ que es **crear.blade.php** es esta

```
@extends('layouts.admin')

@section('title','Creando Usuario')

@section('contenido')
    {!!Form::open(['route'=>'admin.usuario.store','method'=>'POST'])!!}
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('name','Nombre: ')!!}
            {!!Form::text('name',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingresa tu nombre','required'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('email','email: ')!!}
            {!!Form::email('email',null,['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingresa tu Email','required'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('password','Password: ')!!}
            {!!Form::password('password',['class'=>'form-control','placeholder'=>'Ingresa tu contraseña','required'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::label('tipo','Tipo de Usuario: ')!!}
            {!!Form::select('tipoUsuario',[''=>'Selecciona tipo de Usuario','Administrador'=>'Administrador','Moderador'=>'Moderador','Invitado'=>'Invitado'],null,['class'=>'form-control','required'])!!}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            {!!Form::submit('Registrar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}
        </div>

    {!!Form::close()!!}

@stop
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple vista y por lo que veo en la parte inicial del archivo:

```
use Blog\Http\Requests; <---- es un namespace, no una clase
use Blog\Http\Requests\CrearUsuarioRequests; <---- es la clase que necesitas
```

por consiguiente el método store debería utilizar la clase correcta en la inyección de dependencias, en este caso el request para la validación:

```
public function store(CrearUsuarioRequests $request){
    dd($request->all());  
}
```

Comment: Hice el cambio y me genera el mismo error pero ahora con "Class Blog\Http\Requests\CrearUsuarioRequests does not exist"

Comment: Entonces tienes que mirar tu esquema de archivos, si los estás llamando como se debe, o estás agregando/quitando letras. de hecho la clase del request debería llamarse en singular y no en plural. Normalmente debería ser CrearUsuarioRequest, pero aún así depende de tus archivos, tus namespace y el nombre de la clase en el archivo como tal.

Comment: De nuevo gracias :D mi clase estaba en singular y las llamadas eran en plural.

Comment: Si la respuesta fue útil, ya sabes que hacer.